# Pandas Group-by Multiple Columns Period() Key error

Tags: python, pandas

Having a bit of problems with fetching a pandas group from a multiple column group by, my guess is that I am missing something small and that's hopefully the case. Here's a test case that will demonstrate the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 
                     'date' : [pd.Timestamp('2016-12-1'), pd.Timestamp('2016-12-1'),pd.Timestamp('2016-11-1'),pd.Timestamp('2016-11-1')],
                     'number' : np.array(list(range(4)),dtype='int32'),
                     'category' : pd.Categorical(["test","other","test","other"]),
                     'this' : 'foo' })

print(df2)

        category       date  number this
    0     test 2016-12-01       0  foo
    1    other 2016-12-01       1  foo
    2     test 2016-11-01       2  foo
    3    other 2016-11-01       3  foo

df2['period'] = df2.date.dt.to_period("M")

print(df2)

      category       date  number this  period
    0     test 2016-12-01       0  foo 2016-12
    1    other 2016-12-01       1  foo 2016-12
    2     test 2016-11-01       2  foo 2016-11
    3    other 2016-11-01       3  foo 2016-11

grouped1 = df2.groupby(['period'])

print(grouped1.groups)
    {Period('2016-12', 'M'): [0, 1], Period('2016-11', 'M'): [2, 3]}

print(grouped1.get_group(pd.Period('2016-12', 'M')))
      category       date  number this  period
    0     test 2016-12-01       0  foo 2016-12
    1    other 2016-12-01       1  foo 2016-12

grouped2 = df2.groupby(['period', 'category'])

print(grouped2.groups)
    {(Period('2016-11', 'M'), 'test'): [2], (Period('2016-11', 'M'), 'other'): [3], (Period('2016-12', 'M'), 'other'): [1], (Period('2016-12', 'M'), 'test'): [0]}

print(grouped2.get_group((pd.Period('2016-11', 'M'), 'test')))
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      .....
      File "C:/Users/XXXX/XXXX/testcase.py", line 32, in <module>
print(grouped2.get_group((pd.Period('2016-11', 'M'), 'test')))

      File "F:\Python\WinPython-32bit-3.4.4.1\python-3.4.4\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 648, in get_group
raise KeyError(name)

    KeyError: (Period('2016-11', 'M'), 'test')
```

As you can see a `get_group` call on a Period object when it is the single vector for grouping works perfectly fine. But when it is a part of a multiple column grouping it throws a `name key error` because the `Period()` part of the `get_group` tuple can't be found.

My guess is when the object `pd.Period()` is in the tuple form required for the multiple column `get_group` it's possibly not evaluating?

I've tried just using what the `Period()` should evaluate to eg `2016-11` but still get the name key error.

Grasping at straws I tried to `stringify` the `Period('2016-11', 'M')` as well as set it as `x = Period('2016-11', 'M')` but neither was able to run without name key errors.

As a sanity check I tried:

```
grouped2 = df2.groupby(['this', 'category'])

print(grouped2.groups)

print(grouped2.get_group(('foo', 'test')))
```

Which obviously works fine.

Is there some sort of tricky method that I can make the `Period()` objects 'nameable'? Or is there something I am totally missing?

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. I ran your code straight through just fine. Try converting the groups to a list and using get_groups on the first element of that list. `a = list(grouped2.groups)` and then `grouped2.get_group(a[0])`

Comment: I reproduce the error in pandas 0.18, and not in pandas 0.19. Can you upgrade?

Comment: Upgrading cleared it up, for reference in case it's helpful to others I had been on 0.17.1. Thank you.